# Is it possible for a client to kill a long-running Postgres query?

Tags: postgresql

A client makes a request to a Postgres database for data. The database is too slow to respond. Is it possible for the client to send a CANCEL request or something to tell Postgres to stop working on the query?

Comment: It is possible to send a ctrl+c or similar from the client that runs the query.  Otherwise, it is only possible to kill it with `pg_terminate_backend()`, that needs superuser rights.  Or it can be sent a SIGTERM from the OS, if you have access there.

Comment: `pg_terminate_backend` and `pg_cancel_backend` do *not* require superuser rights on 9.2 or above if you're terminating a connection owned by the same user. So if you're on a recent version, use that.

Answer (score 2):

Possible workaround: we created a stored procedure for users that would accept a PID to be killed (eg: `sp_kill 4221`) and would write the requesting user name and PID into a table.  That table was checked every 5 minutes by a script.  If the PID requested belonged to the user who requested it and it was still active (ie, `select pid, usename from pg_stat_activity;`) then the superuser would do the kill on the user's behalf.

Note that we only implemented this in development.